# Azure Storage 403 Unauthorized from Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service

after the last update of Azure Storage I get some 403 when I try to upload or modify files on my blob storage.

My code is really easy and I think it's not a "time-related" issue 'cause both App and Storage are on Europe-West dataserver.

My code is really simple:

```
var connectionString =[MyCs, always working]
account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(Name);
if (container.Exists()) return container.Name;
container.CreateIfNotExists();
```

The error I get is like:

```
The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer.Create(BlobContainerPublicAccessType accessType, BlobRequestOptions requestOptions, OperationContext operationContext) at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExists(BlobContainerPublicAccessType accessType, BlobRequestOptions requestOptions, OperationContext operationContext) at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExists(BlobRequestOptions requestOptions, OperationContext operationContext) at HouseParty.AzureStorage.<CreateFile>d__6.MoveNext() in C:\Users\zibal\Source\Repos\HouseParty\HouseParty\AzureStorage.cs:line 51 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at HouseParty.Utils.<AddMedia>d__4.MoveNext() in C:\Users\zibal\Source\Repos\HouseParty\HouseParty\Utils.cs:line 77 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at HouseParty.Controllers.MediaController.<StaticAdd>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\Users\zibal\Source\Repos\HouseParty\HouseParty\Controllers\MediaController.cs:line 89 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at HouseParty.Controllers.UsersController.<Test>d__20.MoveNext() in C:\Users\zibal\Source\Repos\HouseParty\HouseParty\Controllers\UsersController.cs:line 271
```

P.S.: already tried to rollback to prev version from NUGET
P.P.S.: Code working from LOCALHOST

Comment: For your connection string, are you using Shared Access Signature by any chance?

Comment: No, I'm using the REAL connection string, I tryed the Primary and secondary!

Comment: And you're getting an error when you try to create the container? What version of storage client library are you using?

Comment: I get the error in every case when I try to CREATE or EDIT something. I tried with client 8.0.0, 8.0.1 and the latest (i think 8.1.1)

Comment: Could it be a "CORS-related" problem?

Comment: No, it can't be CORS. Only browsers care about CORS. OP is not embedding anything anywhere. I would suggest you try to deploy the app to a new Web App instance, there could be something stuck there. A 403 is pretty odd though as the server basically is saying "I know who you are but you are not allowed to do that". Did you by chance change something related to the connection string recently?

Comment: No, I haven't changed anything. I changed right now the time zone to have the same timing on App Service and Storage but still not working. If I try from localhost, everyhing works fine. When I deploy it, everything is broken. I think I'll wipe out the bin folder and see if it helps somehow.

Comment: You changed the timezone? Did you change it before? Everything runs on UTC by default otherwise.

Comment: No, haven't changed timezone, actually I tried to change it with no result

Comment: I suggest you could check the application settings in the web app service. If you set the connection string in it, it will overwrite your webconfig's connection string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 3 hours with the Microsoft Service, we came out with noticing something strange in the request from my Web App.

We turned on the analytics POSTing here:

The REST API we used to capture network trace is

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription_ID>/resourceGroups/<Resource_Group_Name>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<site_name>/networkTrace/start?duration=<duration_in_seconds>&api-version=2015-08-01
```

with headers

```
 Authorization: the token we get from portal
 Content-Type: application/json
```

Then we can check the logs under \LogFiles\networktrace in Kudu portal. There where was this exception:

```
  Processing exception Microsoft.Cis.Services.Nephos.Common.Authentication.AuthenticationFailureException : The MAC signature found in the HTTP request '*****************' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'PUT...7.***********==........x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob.x-ms-client-request-id:********.x-ms-date:Mon, 15 May 2017 08:56:41 GMT.x-ms-request-id:*****.x-ms-version:2016-05-31./housepartystorage/img/test'.
```

And my request (created by the Azure SDK) was like

```
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
PUT /img/test HTTP/1.1\r\n
    [Expert Info (Chat/Sequence): PUT /img/test HTTP/1.1\r\n]
        [PUT /img/test HTTP/1.1\r\n]
        [Severity level: Chat]
        [Group: Sequence]
    Request Method: PUT
    Request URI: /img/test
    Request Version: HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Azure-Storage/8.1.1 (.NET CLR 4.0.30319.42000; Win32NT 6.2.9200.0)\r\n
x-ms-version: 2016-05-31\r\n
Content-MD5: LAT5h1nXhLLXm9cujfJFfA==\r\n
x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob\r\n
x-ms-client-request-id: 95933c6d-144e-4295-9bcd-405aba4bedf6\r\n
x-ms-date: Mon, 15 May 2017 08:56:39 GMT\r\n
Authorization: SharedKey MYBLOB:+[SECRET]=\r\n
x-ms-request-id: 5+l1WofovW0=\r\n
Host: [MYBLOB].blob.core.windows.net\r\n
Content-Length: 7\r\n
    [Content length: 7]
\r\n
[Full request URI: http://MYBLOB.blob.core.windows.net/img/test]
[HTTP request 3/5]
[Response in frame: 30]
[Next request in frame: 31]
File Data: 7 bytes
Data (7 bytes)
    Data: 20202020202020
    [Length: 7]
```

And it turns out my App was adding an extra header like:

```
 x-ms-request-id
```

This extra header came from MICROSOFT APPLICATION INSIGHT.

After disabled (uninstall from NUGET) of Application Insight, everything worked fine again!

Answer (score 0):

We commented this line out at wwwroot/applicationinsights.config in our app service

-->

This removed additional headers.

Please give it a try.

Comment: we commented this line out at wwwroot/applicationinsights.config in our app service

<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector"/>